# GT Metrix Add Expires headers

Tags: php, wordpress, gtmetrix

I have tested my site in GT Metrix and received the below result.

```
Add Expires headers

There are 5 static components without a far-future expiration date.

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C600%2C700%2C800%7CLato%3Aregular%2C700%2Cregular%2C700%7CDancing+Script%3Aregular%2Cdefault
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1071.min.js
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

These resources are hosted on an external server, which you don't have access to. Which means that you cannot add expires headers to these files.